# On careers.stackoverflow long tags break technology like/dislike saving

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

**To reproduce:**

Go to your profile

Click edit under "Technologies"

For likes enter "PHP"

For dislikes enter "Fashioning-rudimentary-stone-tools-from-sticks-and-rocks-held-together-with-sinew Java"

Press save

**Expected result:**

Either save as requested or provide a helpful error message like "People who know how to use the internet generally use short, generic, searchable terms as tags.  Looks like you'll be stuck working in the adult diaper manufacturer's customer returns department for a while longer"

**Actual result:**

Button shows "Saving" forever.

It looks like it does save, so maybe it works the first time, but the response is an error so the DOM update does not change the button back.

Comment: +1 When it comes to error messages, the snarkier the better, I say.

Answer (score 1):

The expected behavior is what's happening right now, we cleaned this up a long time ago.